# Excel fucntion transpose If same Value

Tags: excel, transpose

I have these two columns in excel which showing the cluster and the code

```
CLUSTER      Code 
0            Location-24616
0            30197203
1            Location-38146
1            Location-38146
1            PH20628
```

How do I transpose the data this way?

```
CLUSTER             CLUSTER  CODE           CLUSTER    CODE     
0   Location-24616      0    30197203       
1   Location-38146      1    Location-38146    1     PH20628
```

I **do not** need to keep the Cluster Column which is just duplicates.

Comment: It would be better if you tried something and asked a question when you got stuck. There are many examples around of transposing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another column like below and insert the formula to calculate a serial #

[image]

The formula in the cell A2 is

```
=IF(B2=B1,A1+1,1)
```

After that filter the the value in column A and copy paste to a new sheet for each 1,2,3 .....